# AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'read' using image open

Tags: python, image, function

So I have been getting this error and I have been trying so many other things was wondering if someone knew how I could fix this? I'll provide my whole code here.

```
import random #importing libraries 
import urllib.request
 

print("This system is for downloading url images from the internet on to your files/computer")

def yes(): #defining the function yes to get a url image 
  foo = input("Would you like to download an image from a different browser to your files? ENTER YES or NO: ")
  if foo == ("YES"):
    def down_load_imag(url):
      name = random.randrange(1, 1000)
      full_name = str(name) + ".jpg"
      urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, full_name)
    url = input('Enter url pleass open image in a new tab then use that website url: ')
    # here you can evaluate url with regex and if passed:
    down_load_imag (url)
    Nextstep()
  else: 
    print('Image Couldn\'t be retreived')

    yes()

def Nextstep(): #asking if it would like to zoom into the page remember the user has to first name the file they would like and then add to code 
  foo = input ("Would you like to zoom into the image, if yes enter K if no then you can click on your new image that was downoloaded to your files: ")
  if foo == ("K"):
    inputvalue() #allowing user to decide if they would like to explore the images further if not then their image is in their files folder if yes continues with the code 
  else:
    print('that is not a valid option')
    Nextstep()


 #this resizes your image into 4 different ways 
def inputvalue(): #still trying to find a way to take in an input where the user submites its image that it would lile to download and zoom into#update this os working
    zoo = input('Enter the name of the file that was saved to your files in the previous step: ')
   
    doublechecking()
def doublechecking():
  foo = input ("Are you ready for the next step? enter 'L' for yes if not make sure youre ready ")
  if foo == ("L"):
    import os
    import sys
    import numpy as np
    from scipy.interpolate import griddata
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    from PIL import Image
    import random 
    def make_interpolated_image(nsamples):
        """Make an interpolated image from a random selection of pixels.

        Take nsamples random pixels from im and reconstruct the image using
        scipy.interpolate.griddata.

        """

        ix = np.random.randint(im.shape[1], size=nsamples)
        iy = np.random.randint(im.shape[0], size=nsamples)
        samples = im[iy,ix]
        int_im = griddata((iy, ix), samples, (Y, X))
        return int_im

        # Read in image and convert to greyscale array object
    img_name = sys.argv[1]
    name = inputvalue 
    im = Image.open(name) #user has to download image from web first make sure the image is here in the code so it can read it 
    #on to the files of the user 
    im = np.array(im.convert('L'))

    # A meshgrid of pixel coordinates
    nx, ny = im.shape[1], im.shape[0]
    X, Y = np.meshgrid(np.arange(0, nx, 1), np.arange(0, ny, 1))

    # Create a figure of nrows x ncols subplots, and orient it appropriately
    # for the aspect ratio of the image.
    nrows, ncols = 2, 2
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2, figsize=(6,4), dpi=100)
    if nx < ny:
            w, h = fig.get_figwidth(), fig.get_figheight()
            fig.set_figwidth(h), fig.set_figheight(w)

    # Convert an integer i to coordinates in the ax array
    get_indices = lambda i: (i // nrows, i % ncols)

    # Sample 100, 1,000, 10,000 and 100,000 points and plot the interpolated
    # images in the figure
    for i in range(4):
        nsamples = 10**(i+2)
        axes = ax[get_indices(i)]
        axes.imshow(make_interpolated_image(nsamples),
                              cmap=plt.get_cmap('Greys_r'))
        axes.set_xticks([])
        axes.set_yticks([])
        axes.set_title('nsamples = {0:d}'.format(nsamples))
    filestem = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(img_name))[0]
    plt.savefig('{0:s}_interp.png'.format(filestem), dpi=100) #saving the image to files
```

Comment: You forgot the `()` to call the function here: `name = inputvalue`

Comment: Please, try to follow a tutorial and learn fundamentals and get some exposure to proper style, before trying to write your own programs using third-party libraries. The code that you show here suggests a lot of copying and pasting, and not very much thinking. It is only possible to write correct code reliably if you understand what you are writing, as you write it.